# Is it a good practice to pass a Ref as an argument to a service?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, dio

I'm playing with Flutter coming from a Xamarin.Forms experience and I'm trying to implement some common scenarios I dealt with in my previous applications.

I have a `RestClient` service class containing all the low-level Rest calls performed with `Dio`.

I want to logout from the application when one of the calls returns `401 - Unauthorized` (I know it can be handled  better... I'm simplifying).

I'm using `Riverpod` to manage my business logic and I was struggling to try to communicate with an `authenticationProvider`, because  inside `RestClient` there is no `Ref` to interact with providers.

The only way I found was to pass a `Ref` in `RestClient` constructor, so that I can update `authenticationProvider` state.

While it's working fine, I'm doubtful about mixing things and creating a deep link between two components that maybe should not communicate in this way.

Here's my code.

`rest_client.dart`

```dart
class RestClient {
  final Dio dio;
  final Ref ref;

  RestClient._({required this.dio, required this.ref});

  factory RestClient({required Ref ref}) {
    var dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: "https://myurl.com/",
      connectTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),
      receiveTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),
    ));

    dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
      onError: (e, handler) {
        if (e.response != null && e.response!.statusCode == 401) {
          ref.read(authenticationProvider.notifier).invalidateToken();
        }
      },
    ));

    return RestClient._(dio: dio, ref: ref);
  }

  /**** ... *****/
  /**** Methods to call api endpoints *****/
  /**** ... *****/
}
```

`authentication_provider.dart`

```dart
class AutenthicationNotifier extends StateNotifier<String?> {
  // *** Constructor and other methods ***

  void invalidateToken() {
    // body
  }
}

final authenticationProvider = StateNotifierProvider<AutenthicationNotifier, String?>((ref) {
  return AutenthicationNotifier();
});
```

Finally, I have a simple `Provider` that gives access to `RestClient`.

```dart
final restClientProvider = Provider((ref) => RestClient(ref: ref));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the exact way that you should do it. If the class used has its own provider function using ref is the intended way to communicate. After all from the perspective of riverpod the only difference between the two is one having a state.

A syntax suggestion: You can make your RestClient much simpler by just having the constructor  
`RestClient({required this.dio, required this.ref});` 
and doing all the initialization in the provider function:

```
final restClientProvider = Provider((ref) {
 var dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: "https://myurl.com/",
      connectTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),
      receiveTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),
    ));

    dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
      onError: (e, handler) {
        if (e.response != null && e.response!.statusCode == 401) {
          ref.read(authenticationProvider.notifier).invalidateToken();
        }
      },
    ));
return RestClient(ref: ref, dio: dio);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! For your syntax hint, too.

Comment: I have the same question. Thanks for your example. Do you have any reference?

Comment: I find it hard to give a clear reference to this. But to further illustrate my point: riverpod 2 introduced Notifier and AsyncNotifier which both give class wide access to the ref. This pattern is now part of the api.